# 2016: Firefox Replacement for Adobe Flash

Tags: 16.04, firefox, flash

Two-part Question.  My box is 16.04

As I understand it: Adobe Flash for Linux is no longer supported and I am wondering if the security updates are supported?

What is the plan to replace Adobe Flash with a successor in Firefox (on Ubuntu)?  Perhaps this has already happened?

Comment: flash still gets security updates, just not new versions like on Windows, you can install it with `sudo apt install flashplugin-installer` or it is part of the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` packages, it works fine for me. I don't know about any future plans though.

Comment: This is not wholly true. First, there's Pepper Flash, which is the upstream code for Flash, being worked on by Google under NDA with Adobe. Second, Flash is deprecated  for many reasons, one you just mentioned. Every more-or-less respectable site already moved to HTML5. Other ones keeping up. FYI, I'm using Firefox without Flash player for a long time, and didn't notice any problem.

Comment: @Hi-Angel is correct about Pepper Flash. You'll find it in Synaptic. It will update you from an unsupported Adobe Flash v11.2 to the current flash supplied in Chrome which is v21. You'll need to have Chrome installed. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adobe Flash Player for Firefox is updated again. The latest version of the `adobe-flashplugin` package in [Canonical Partner](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner) installs version 24.0.0.186 of both the NPAPI and PPAPI plugin.

Comment: Exciting news: is there an example of how to acquire the .so file and test to confirm Flash 23 is properly installed?  If so, maybe update the answer?  Thank you

Comment: @gatorback: I did that, kind of.

Answer (score 4):

Adobe Flash player for Firefox 11.2 is still supported.

Alternatively you can use Pepper Flash for Chromium based browsers. It is installed by default in Google Chrome.

Recently Adobe announced that they will update NPAPI Flash player 11.2 soon and will keep it up to date with Pepper Flash.