# Need help with adobe flash player in abuntu 16.04.1 firefox LTS

Tags: flash, adobe

I have adobe flash player installed, but still doesnt let me view web cams on adultfriendfinder. I have the latest version of adobe flash player and when I go to view the web cams it still says to download adobe flash player. Someone help me fix it or if you can fix it remotely. Or if you can post exactly what i need to do in the terminal or make a video of what I need to do to fix this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Adobe Flash for Linux is... well... errmm... Let's just say, *for all intents and purposes*, it may as well not exist. (If you'd like a technical explanation, I can provide that)

Your best bet is going to be to install Google Chrome, because there is an actively maintained Linux version, and it includes support for Flash.

To install Chrome, first open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

Next, download the .deb file from Google. Finally, double-click it, and Software Center will open, and you can install it.

Comment: I get the following messages..

Comment: dell@dell-Inspiron-1545:~$ apt-get update
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)

Comment: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
dell@dell-Inspiron-1545:~$

Comment: @RoyRodriguez You didn't use `sudo`, hence the message "are you root?"

Comment: @RoyRodriguez - As wjandrea said, you **must** use `sudo`.

Comment: Your statement about Adobe Flash for Linux, and the following recommendation to switch to Chrome for that reason, is [a bit obsolete](http://askubuntu.com/questions/817182/2016-firefox-replacement-for-adobe-flash/823307#823307), so I downvoted your answer.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson - **1st**: thank you for actually leaving a comment as to why you downvoted. **2nd**: Wait; **WHAT!?** After 4 years they start supporting Linux again? **O_O** Although, I will say, I don't think the info I provided should be considered *obsolete*, considering that this only happened within the last month.

Comment: In any case it's good news, right? If you update your answer, and add something about that beta flash, I'll remove the downvote. (Not possible to do that without an edit.)

Comment: I need help with the next step :

Comment: Next, download the .deb file from Google. Finally, double-click it, and Software Center will open, and you can install it.

Comment: I dont know how to download a .deb file from google.

Comment: @RoyRodriguez - simply go to this link: https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Comment: I have the latest google chrome installed and the latest adobe flash player and i still  cant view web cams on adultfriendfinder.