# Sites that use SSO don't work on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, flash, single-sign-on

If I go onto any site that uses some form of SSO it will not work.  For example, if I go to http://www.espn.com/watchespn/index and select a random live stream, it asks me to sign into my service provider.  Once I select my service provider it takes me to their site where I sign in and I automatically get redirected back to their site.  But the video never loads.  This isn't just for espn.com.  If I go to any other site like nbcsports.com or tbs.com to watch tv shows I have the same problem. I've tried this in chrome, chromium, and Firefox (although only chrome supports adobe flash).

I see nothing in console output or network to indicate any issues.  How can I debug this? Can anyone else confirm this issue? I've tried multiple Ubuntu machines and all have same results.

Comment: The sites you mentioned all sound like AV streaming websites. Have you checked to make sure that it's not a problem with playing videos?

Comment: Do you have extensions enabled?

Comment: Without knowing if it's necessary at those sites, it's worth mentioning that there are [Flash plugins available for both Chromium and Firefox](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.10/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html). Chrome OTOH has it built-in to start with.

Comment: @OwenHines yes for example if I go to youtube.com i can play any video without any issues or if I go to a site like http://myp2p.ec/ (careful adware) I can stream audio/video fine.  It is only when a site directs be to my cable service provider's website to enter my credentials and  then returns me back to their site aftwards, that I experience the issue (SSO).  Not sure if this error is relevant but this is what I see in console in dev tools: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: @Olathe I did not know you can enable/disable all extensions.  How do you check that? If I go into extensions all the ones I use are checked enabled though.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson  according to http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Flash-Player-on-Ubuntu that is no longer accurate.  If you read the top it says it's only supported on chrome or chromium.  It's unforunate even Ubuntu's default web browser does not have flash capability.  Anyone in Ubuntu land can surely reproduce my issue as I've reproduced it on at least 5 Ubuntu machines and it works on Mac/Windows.

Comment: @mdo123: Sorry, but it's the page you linked to which is obsolete. ;) The `adobe-flashplugin` package provides Flash for both Firefox and Chromium. As regards Firefox it's still an old version, but for the time being you can install a [modified version of `adobe-flashplugin` from a PPA](http://askubuntu.com/a/823307) with Flash Player 23 (beta) for Firefox.

Comment: @mdo123 I mean that it's a good idea to disable all the extensions one by one in chrome://extensions, then check whether the sites work. If they do work, enable extensions one at a time until they don't work again.