# How to install Flash standalone player on trusty 64-bit

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, flash

I am aware of the player located here: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html and I have downloaded the projector file for linux and unpacked it.  However, I can't get the thing to work....  Any suggestions?

Comment: You can install Google Chrome.  It has flash support built-in.  However, flash is being phased out by end of this year.

Comment: @Dorian: No, Flash will not be phased out so soon. Please see [this article](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2016/07/20/reducing-adobe-flash-usage-in-firefox/).

Comment: Please clarify in your question how Adobe Flash isn't working. Before we can help you, you have to narrow down your question by adding more details. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Wrong, I was talking about Chrome.  Articles [here](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-36301904), [here](https://www.cnet.com/news/google-to-block-flash-on-chrome-only-10-websites-exempt/), and [here](http://www.informationweek.com/software/enterprise-applications/google-ending-automatic-chrome-support-for-flash/d/d-id/1325533).  Also, Adobe itself is even [giving it up in a way](http://home.bt.com/tech-gadgets/computing/could-it-be-the-end-of-the-road-for-adobe-flash-find-out-about-the-security-risks-and-what-you-should-do-about-it-11364012393659). HTML5 is the way forward.

Comment: @Dorian: Ok, then we were talking about different things, and we were both right in a sense, weren't we? ;) Wonder if users will be able to use the PPAPI Flash plugin with Chrome, as they currently can do with Chromium...

Answer (score 1):

1) You could install Google Chrome which has flash plugin built in
or

2) Use this command to install flash-plugin `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`
or

3) If you wish to use Chromium or Firefox follow this guide [Install Flash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Partner-Flash)

- Enable canonical partners in software sources
- Run `sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`

Comment: I need the standalone player rather than the plugin.  I want to play a local .swf file that needs a standalone player.  I got it working through wine.

Answer (score 1):

[Enable the Canonical Partner repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner) and install the `adobe-flashplugin` package. It installs Flash for both Firefox and Chromium.

As regards Firefox the official version is pretty old, but there is a [Flash Plugin 23 Beta in pipeline](https://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2016/08/beta-news-flash-player-npapi-for-linux.html#sthash.3X3ZPVZP.2xXCOi6z.dpbs). If you want the beta version for Firefox in advance, you can install a modified version of `adobe-flashplugin` from [a PPA of mine](https://askubuntu.com/a/823307).

Comment: I need the standalone player rather than the plugin.  I want to play a local .swf file that needs a standalone player.  I got it working through wine.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading and running the projector files that you linked worked fine for me. Here's a picture (with my name blacked out):

[image: Image of a flash program running]

Either just giving the file as an argument in the terminal or pasting the .swf file's location in the URL bar after executing it worked for me with both the debugger and non-debugger versions.