# pepperflashplugin-nonfree package installation fails since Chrome 54 is out (October 12th, 2016)

Tags: google-chrome, flash, pepperflash

The installation of `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` for instance using the command

```
apt-get install --reinstall pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

fails with the error message:

```
mv: cannot evaluate 'unpackchrome/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so': No file or folder of this type
```

Comment: @Android Dev thanks for the edit, I was looking for that :-)

Comment: For instructions installing flash see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/852416/22338).

Comment: @Mike I would recommend installing Flash with the package `adobe-flashplugin` instead, this way Flash is automatically updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` downloads the Chrome for Linux Debian package (.deb) from Google and extracts the Flash PPAPI plugin (`libpepflashplayer.so`) to make it available to other browsers system-wide.

The package `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` is broken since Google changed the method of distribution of the Flash plugin with Chrome 54 for Linux; `libpepflashplayer.so` is not directly bundled in the Debian package anymore.

[A bug report is available on Launchpad.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/+bug/1632870)

Since the Flash plugin is often affected by critical vulnerabilities and `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` currenlty fails to update the plugin, `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` should not be used anymore and either `adobe-flashplugin` from Canonical Partner or no Flash plugin at all should be used.

If you use Flash you can check the version of your Flash plugin [on this support page on the Adobe website](https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/).

Comment: Hmm.. People should be advised to install `adobe-flashplugin` from Canonical Partner instead. If `adobe-flashplugin` hadn't been in Canonical Partner (not enabled by default), the `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` package could have been converted to a transitional dummy package.

Comment: I added some background information and a hint about `adobe-flashplugin`.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Ubuntu just updated my Chrome but I haven't rebooted yet. Chrome settings says I'm on `Version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit)`. Are you saying when I reboot and reload Chrome it will be `54` and my flash player would be broken, so I should downgrade the package? (October 12, 6pm MST).

Comment: From what I saw the Chrome 54 Debian package removes the Flash plugin from your system libraries and Chrome 54 will download the current version of the plugin to your home folder  the first time you will load some Flash content. The details are on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/+bug/1632870).

Comment: @StéphaneTréboux So it didn't actually happen to you, you're posting the bug report? I know chromium had problems before but I'm using Chrome. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Chrome users don't need `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` and are not affected; Google still distributes the Flash PPAPI plugin for Chrome; the plugin is silently downloaded by Chrome.  `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` is meant to install the Flash PPAPI plugin to be available system wide for other browsers like Chromium and Firefox (via freshplayerplugin) and is now broken. Just try to run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall pepperflashplugin-nonfree` and see for yourself.

Comment: @StéphaneTréboux But I'm using Chrome, why would I install broken software for something I'm not using?

Comment: You can install broken software to see for yourself that it's broken and understand why I filed a bug report :-) I use Firefox with Flash PPAPI and I am affected.

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson thanks for your hint, I was not aware of that and I corrected my answer accordingly. Still this raises more problems in my case (Firefox with freshplayerplugin) because I am not able to choose the version of the plugin I want to use and I am stuck with the old NPAPI plugin. I read recently that [Adobe is working again on the NPAPI plugin for Linux](https://www.heise.de/security/meldung/Totgesagte-leben-laenger-Adobe-poliert-NPAPI-Flash-auf-Linux-auf-3314084.html) so it may be moot anyway. I will continue investigation tomorrow, it is time to sleep for me :-)

Comment: @StéphaneTréboux: As regards Firefox I make the Flash Player 23 Beta [available in  a PPA](http://askubuntu.com/q/823307).