# Distribution upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 stuck installing pepperflashplugin-nonfree (amd64)

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, flash

What should I do?  I have a "Distribution Upgrade" window open. It has green check marks along "Preparing to upgrade", "Setting new software channels" and "Getting new packages."  It is currently on the "Installing the upgrades" step, and is hanging on "Preparing pepperflashplugin-nonfree (amd64)". There is an expandable/collapsible terminal at the bottom of the "Distribution Upgrade" window, but no text is visible (it is all black), and when I click on it it flashes.

My screenshot application does not open (perhaps because the upgrade is in progress?), but I can still open chrome.  What should I do?  Should I restart my machine?  Early in the upgrade I was warned not to turn off my machine until the upgrade was complete.  What should I do now that it is hanging part way through?

Edit: the screenshot tool no longer opens, but apparently gimp does.  Here is a screenshot:

[image: frozen distribution upgrade]

When I click on "Terminal" the black rectangle flashes (without changing size, i.e. it does not open up).  If I right click on the "Distribution Upgrade" bar at the top of the window, the Minimize, Maximize and Resize options are all greyed out.

Edit:  here is the output from `ps aux | grep flashplugin`:

```
root     15540  0.0  4.4 287072 266080 pts/12  Ss+  00:08   0:01 /usr/bin/dpkg --force-overwrite --status-fd 80 --unpack --auto-deconfigure /var/cache/apt/archives/pepperflashplugin-nonfree_1.8.2ubuntu1_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pymysql_0.7.2-1_all.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/cabextract_1.6-1_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu2_all.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/snap-confine_1.0.43-0ubuntu1~16.04.1_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-core-launcher_1.0.43-0ubuntu1~16.04.1_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/unity-gtk-module-common_0.0.0+15.04.20150118-0ubuntu2_all.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/unity-gtk2-module_0.0.0+15.04.20150118-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/unity-gtk3-module_0.0.0+15.04.20150118-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/vlc-plugin-samba_2.2.2-5_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl3_7.47.0-1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/whoopsie_0.2.52.1_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/libwhoopsie0_0.2.52.1_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/libss2_1.42.13-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
adrian   17739  4.7  4.3 3027800 261616 ?      SLl  00:29   0:52 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version --enable-pinch
adrian   17757  0.0  0.9 441452 57596 ?        S    00:29   0:00 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=zygote --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version
adrian   17761  0.0  0.1 441452 11176 ?        S    00:29   0:00 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=zygote --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version
adrian   19670  0.0  0.0  18372   988 tty1     S+   00:47   0:00 grep --color=auto flashplugin
```

Got another warning -- don't know whether this is related to the earlier problems:

[image]

Comment: I ran sudo kill -9 15540, got a warning that a package was not installed correctly, and now the installation is progressing...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pepperflashplugin-nonfree package installation fails since Chrome 54 is out (October 12th, 2016)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/836261/pepperflashplugin-nonfree-package-installation-fails-since-chrome-54-is-out-oct)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably related to [bug #1632870](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/+bug/1632870).

I'd suggest that you [enable Canonical Partner](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner) and then run:

```
sudo apt purge pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
```

The `adobe-flashplugin` package will install an updated version of `libpepflashplayer.so`. It will also install `libflashplayer.so` for e.g. Firefox.