# Need to get Flash running on Firefox 49.0 using 14.04

Tags: flash

I currently have libflashplayer.so in the mozilla plugin folder, but still flash is not working with Firefox 49.0 under Ubuntu 14.04?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Been at this for a look time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The official Flash Player for Firefox is a rather old version, but there is Flash Player 23 Beta which sooner or later will be official.

If you want to install the beta now, I made a [modified version of `adobe-flashplugin` available in a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/823307).